# Is there an effective way of deciding whether a given Godel numbers for a formula or a sequence of formulas??

Tags: logic, computability

If we have a Godel number, how can we tell that this number for a formula or for a sequence of formulas effectively?
If we have X is a Godel number of some formula, then we can consider this formula as a sequence of formulas which just containing itself and compute its corresponding Godel number which is 2^X which means that we have two Godel numbers for same formula. Any explanations please??

Comment: "we can consider this formula as a sequence of formulas which just containing itself" An object is different from the length-one sequence consisting of just that object (analogously to how $\{\}\not=\{\{\}\}$).

Comment: Every number is effectively a code for a finite sequence of numbers. So that really depends on your coding scheme.

Comment: Short answer is yes.  The crux of many Gödel numbering schemes is to uniquely associate a formula or a sequence of formulas to a number by prime factorization.  While the factoring problem may not have polynomial time complexity, it is effectively computable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I know they are different but what does prevent us to consider a sequence as a length-one sequence?.

Comment: I'm not sure tu understand the difficulty... If $n= \ulcorner \varphi \urcorner$ where the formula $\varphi$ is an axiom, we have that $2^n$ encode the 1-line derivation of the axiom itself. Formally, this is correct (also if useless). But there is no real ambiguity: the first one encode a formula, while the second one encode a sequence of formulas and the two entities are "conceptually" different. The basic feature of Godel numbering is that from the code we can univocally find the syntacical entity encoded.

Comment: You can see **Sect.3.4** (page 224-on) of Enderton: *Arithmetization of Syntax*. And see page 184: "We can assign to each formula $α$ of the language of number theory an integer $\ulcorner α \urcorner$, called the Godel number of $α$. Any sufficiently straightforward
way of assigning distinct integers to formulas would suffice
for our purposes [there are many]; a particular assignment is adopted at the beginning of Sect.3.4. **What is important is that from** $α$ **we can effectively find the number** $\ulcorner α \urcorner$, **and conversely**.  1/2

Comment: Similarly, to each finite sequence $D$ of
formulas (such as a *deduction*) we assign an integer $G(D)$." 2/2

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be: Given some natural number, how do we differentiate a Gödel number for a formula from a Gödel number for a sequence of formulas?

There are essentially two answers to this question depending on the Gödel numbering.

The first is that the Gödel numbering makes them unambiguous. For example, in  [Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der Principia Mathematica und verwandter Systeme I](http://www.w-k-essler.de/pdfs/goedel.pdf) by Gödel, a formula is represented by a sequence of symbols. Each symbol is numbered with an odd number while sequences of numbers are encoded into the powers of prime numbers in order and thus every sequence of numbers is even. So if the power of $2$ is $0$, then we know we have a symbol, otherwise we know we have a sequence of numbers. A formula would be an even number whose prime powers are all odd. A sequence of formulas would be an even number whose prime powers are all even numbers whose prime powers are all odd. An even number whose prime powers are a mix of even and odd numbers doesn't correspond to a formula or a sequence of formulas (or a sequence of sequences of formulas etc.)

The second approach is if the Gödel numbering gives two different things the same number, or, more likely, you simply have multiple Gödel numberings for different kinds of things. In this case, context would be used to disambiguate just like how your computer will happily open an image file as a text file if you want. It just interprets the same sequence of bits a different way. If we know we are expecting a sequence of formulas, we interpret the number as a sequence of formulas even if it might possibly also be interpretable as a single formula.

Here's an example. Consider a simple propositional language talking about equality of natural numbers. We have a constant symbol $z$ and a unary function symbol $s$, a binary relation symbol $=$, and the logical connectives $\neg$ and $\land$. Define the Gödel numberings $G_f$ and $G_t$ in the following way:$$G_f(\varphi)=\begin{cases}3^{G_t(t_1)}5^{G_t(t_2)},&\varphi=(t_1=t_2)\\ 2^13^{G_f(\psi)},&\varphi=\neg\psi\\
2^23^{G_f(\psi_1)}5^{G_f(\psi_2)},&\varphi=(\psi_1\land\psi_2)\end{cases}\qquad G_t(t)=\begin{cases}0,& t = z\\1+G_t(t'),& t=s(t')\end{cases}$$

We have $G_f(\varphi)=G_t(s^{G_f(\varphi)}(z))$ where $s^n(z)$ means $z$ if $n=0$ or $s(s^k(z))$ if $n=k+1$. Thus, for every formula there is a term that has the same Gödel numbering. This is not a problem though as long as we know to expect either a term or a formula. For example, given a Gödel numbering of a formula that is a multiple of $4$, we know that the exponents of $3$ and $5$ should be treated as formulas because we are considering the Gödel numbering of $\land$. It doesn't matter that they could *also* be interpreted as terms. We know we are expecting formulas.